# Which is faster: save() or update() Laravel method?

Tags: laravel

I want to increment the calls / views for a blog. In the controller I have the following two lines:

```php
$post->views = $post->views + 1;
$post->save();
```

I wonder if the update method might be faster?

Another question about incrementing. Is there a Laravel function that can be used to increment?

Comment: Laravel add new Benchmark function you can test it and we like to know the results https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#benchmarking

Comment: https://laraveldaily.com/post/eloquent-incrementing-columns-without-update-function for increment

Comment: Given this is a single database write inline the increment method in controller should be quick enough. But if you are worried it might not be you can use an event and have a listener that does the update at the back of that event which will do the same but you can queue the listener meaning its asynchronous and does not effect your request times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, both writing methods should be equally fast. Here is your second question. You can use `increment()`function.

```php
// 1.
Post::where('id', $id)->increment('views');
// 2.
Post::find($id)->increment('views'); 
// 3.
$post->views++;
$post->save();
```

Answer (score 4):

Both methods will be broadly the same, `update()` also calls `save()`.

[From the `Eloquent\Model` API:](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L985)

> ```php
> public function update(array $attributes = [], array $options = [])
> {
>     if (! $this->exists) {
>         return false;
>     }
>     return $this->fill($attributes)->save($options);
> }
> ```